# How to insert a Text at the end of truncated multile text? React Native

Tags: react-native, text, ellipsis, truncated, test-more

I'd like to understand how to add some Text/Button, etc. and the end of ellipsed text last line when we have a truncated multiline text

for example:

```
 Some cool text we can read here
 and feel very positive emotions
 but there is a bit ...[Show More]
```

as you can see the **Show More** text is placed directly in the Text Block (last line). 
The question is: how to achieve it in the case of RN?

We can use  *numberOfLines={3}* to truncate the text and we can use *ellipsizeMode='tail'* to achieve ... dots at the end of the line but I can't find a solution how to put the **Show More** text there. 
I tried to use the Absolute position for Show More but it's a bad idea because each time text could be truncated in another place depends on the sentence words.

Thanks for any help!